# execute javascript in html

Tags: javascript

I'm trying change prices on a website I'm designing. Price values are dynamic (generated by a CMS namely 3dcart) and appear in code as `[ITEMPRICE]`.

Prices have currency symbols and decimal points and I'm trying to remove them with a JavaScript.

This is an example of the HTML

```
<span>[ITEMPRICE]</`span>
```

and value of `itemprice` would for example be `$199.00`. I want the page to show `199` only.

So I tried this :

```
<script>
function chop_price()
{
    [ITEMPRICE] = [ITEMPRICE].replace("$","");
    [ITEMPRICE] = parseInt([ITEMPRICE]);
}
</script>
```

but I don't even know how to execute this function so that the page would change for the value without decimal.

I should add this 3dcart system generates the final HTML based on HTML templates (what I'm trying to edit edit to remove the decimal) and a database containing all product info (like prices etc.). I can edit the template but the final HTML is generated dynamically.

Comment: Call the function inside the `<script>` :`chop_price();`

Comment: `[ITEMPRICE] = ...` is a syntax error or at least a run time error. Whatever you want to do, it has to be done entirely differently .

Comment: alejandro-ivan just gave me the solution. it worked like a charm. Anyhow thanks everybody for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it when the body loads... `<body onload="chop_price();">....</body>` or directly inside a script tag `<script type="text/javascript">chop_price();</script>` after the declaration you mentioned.

What you could do is to insert [ITEMPRICE] inside a div with a class assigned (for example: `<div class="item_price">[ITEMPRICE]</div>`) and select all items that match the class and modify the inner HTML when the body loads.

```
<head>
......
<script type="text/javascript">
function process_prices() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item_price');
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var el = elements[i];
        el.innerHTML = chop_price(el.innerHTML);
    }
}

function chop_price(text) {
    var result = text;
    result = result.replace("$", "");
    result = parseInt(result);

    return result;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="process_prices();">
......
</body>
```

Of course, the best shot is to modify the values in the CMS output.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use JavaScript to modify your template variables.

By the time the browser sees them, the template will have been processed and the variables will have been replaced by values throughout the page.

If you want to modify them with JavaScript, you will need to search through the DOM for the the places that the template placed them, and then modify them there.

That said, the proper place to do this is inside the CMS.

Answer (score -1):

Call the function like this:-

```
<script>
..................
chop_price();
................................
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use window.onload event like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chop_price(){
        [ITEMPRICE] = [ITEMPRICE].replace("$","");
        [ITEMPRICE] = parseInt([ITEMPRICE]);
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        chop_price();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , unfortunatly none of the solutions proposed worked. I should mention that the website works as below : there is a frame html (would have header and footer of website) template and for example a home html template (for the actual content in center). the 3dcart system has a database (with product and price) and the actual final html code is created dynamically. the html templates contains a bunch of [parameter] that pulls data from the database to generate the final page. (so you can change a price in the CMS without touching the actual html code...

Comment: `[ITEMPRICE] = ...` is not even valid JavaScript!

Answer (score -2):

Put this below code segment in your header part of html (your same function)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function chop_price()
{
[ITEMPRICE] = [ITEMPRICE].replace("$","");
[ITEMPRICE] = parseInt([ITEMPRICE]);
}

</script>
```

and if you are calling the function using a button, i assume!

```
<input type="button" value="Remove Doller" onclick="chop_price()" />
```

Comment: `[ITEMPRICE] = ...` is not even valid JavaScript!

Comment: whatever, it can be his variable i guess thats why he put ->[] also i did that way

Comment: That [ITEMPRICE] is a variable for the CMS, like $itemprice would be for PHP. It isn't a Javascript object, that's why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes i know that is not a java script, i thought you gave a temporary name for that variable that's why i did not consider.